# How to replace semicolon with comma for pdfkeywords in hyperref

Tags: hyperref, strings, xstring, keywords

From an external file I get a list with keywords separated by `;`. Since `hyperref` only works with keywords separated by `,` I need to replace the semicola.

Following MWE works for text but not for `pdfkeywords` from `hyperref`

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\def\fmkeywords{Keyword1; Keyword2; Keyword3}
\hypersetup{                    
  unicode,                      
  pdftitle={My title},
  pdfencoding=auto,             
  pdfkeywords={\StrSubstitute{\fmkeywords}{;}{,}},   
}
\begin{document}
wrong: \fmkeywords

correct: \StrSubstitute{\fmkeywords}{;}{,}
\end{document}
```

In the PDF-info it won't display the keywords:

[image: Keywords are not listed]

But all is fine in the text:

[image: Keywords in text work fine]

Answer (score 2):

Expand the substitution and store it in the same variable (`\fmkeywords`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\def\fmkeywords{Keyword1; Keyword2; Keyword3}

\StrSubstitute{\fmkeywords}{;}{,}[\fmkeywords]
\hypersetup{
  unicode,
  pdftitle={My title},
  pdfencoding=auto,
  pdfkeywords={\fmkeywords}
}
\begin{document}

correct: \fmkeywords

correct: \StrSubstitute{\fmkeywords}{;}{,}

\end{document}
```

Comment: this does not work properly as far as I see: In the Dublin Core it is still considered as _one_ keyword: `dc:subject (bag container) -- [1]: Keyword1, Keyword2, Keyword3`

Comment: @LukasCB: Try [this paste](https://pastebin.com/GTiczmH0). It expands the keywords before calling `\hypersetup`.

Comment: Still as if one keyword. No separation internally.

Comment: @LukasCB: And how does that compare to `pdfkeywords={one,two,three}`? Three keywords?

Comment: Yes, then they listed in the dublin core as `[1]: one [2]: two [3]: three` --> three keywords.

Comment: @LukasCB: I'm not familiar with Dublin Core, nor techniques to extract the keyword breakout other than what is provided via Adobe Reader directly, or `pdfinfo`.

Comment: `pdfkeywords={\fmkeywords}` seems to work for me

Comment: @Werner: To see the Dublin Core one need e.g. Adobe Acrobat Pro.